# Will Window's check disk hurt my ext partition?

Tags: filesystem

I'm a bit worried, my Windows8 started a check and repair disk when I booted. It hasn't done this since I installed lubuntu, is Windows going to destroy my linux because it is an unrecognized file system?

Answer (score 6):

Windows' disk check is a filesystem verification tool, and so works on a partition-by-partition basis.  Your Lubuntu installation should be fine because chkdsk won't recognize the filesystem type, and so will exit without modifying it.

Comment: Thank you, I work with computers a lot, but not on a hardware side. I was just worried because it seems to be hanging for a while now.